# Copiar datos de una tabla a otra con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla que muestra datos y otra que sería el histórico de datos de la primera, lo que quisiera es que al pulsar el botón "*guardar*", los datos seleccionados se borren de la tabla principal y se guarden en la tabla del histórico.

Con el código que tengo, consigo que los datos se borren de la principal, pero no que se guarden en la de histórico. Debe de haber algo que no funciona correctamente. Os dejo el código:

```php
<?php

require 'funcs/funcs.php';
require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$checkbox = $_POST['casilla1'];

foreach ($checkbox as $value) {

    $select="Select * from pms where id_pm = $value";
    $result = $mysqli->query($select);
    $listaAlta = $result->fetch_assoc();
    //var_dump ($listaAlta);
        
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO pms_historico (id_pm, canal, kzz, cdPM, modelo, rsProve, poblProve, provProv, cpProv, fechaPM,  fechaFinGarantia,  extenGaran, provPM, poblPM, cpPM, callePM, nPM, pisoPM, tecInstl, tecPM, tipoInst, estadoPM ) 
        VALUES ('".$listaAlta['id_pm']."','".$listaAlta['canal']."','".$listaAlta['kzz']."','".$listaAlta['cdPM']."','".$listaAlta['modelo']."','".$listaAlta['rsProve']."','".$listaAlta['poblProve']."','".$listaAlta['provProv']."','".$listaAlta['cpProv']."','".$listaAlta['fechaPM']."','".$listaAlta['fechaFinGarantia']."','".$listaAlta['extenGaran']."','".$listaAlta['provPM']."','".$listaAlta['poblPM']."','".$listaAlta['cpPM']."','".$listaAlta['callePM']."','".$listaAlta['nPM']."','".$listaAlta['pisoPM']."','".$listaAlta['tecInstl']."','".$listaAlta['tecPM']."','".$listaAlta['tipoInst']."','".$listaAlta['estadoPM']."')";
    $resultado1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
    //var_dump ($sql1);

    $sql = "Delete From pms where id_pm = ".$value."";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($sql1){
    
        echo "Registro guardado <br>";
    }
}

?>
```

El código HTML para mostrar si los registros se han guardado correctamente y volver a la tabla principal:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center"> <br>
        <?php if($resultado) { ?>
            <h3>REGISTRO GUARDADO</h3>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <h3>ERROR AL GUARDAR</h3>
        <?php } ?>

<a href="pmITK.php" class="btn btn-primary">Volvera la tabla de datos</a>
```

En las pruebas que he hecho todo sale correcto, es decir, se borran de la tabla principal y me sale "Registro guardado", pero no se guarda.

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

---

**Update para añadir información:**

En la imagen verás la estructura de ambas trablas, es igual en todo.
[image: Tablas]

Y esto es lo que me sale cuando ejecuto el código `var_export($sql1)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora ya está correcto. Pero sigue sin copiarse
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si haces `var_export($sql1)` y lo que te da lo ejecutas con MySQL, se agrega la fila en la tabla?

Comment: No, me da este error "La columna '17822' en field list es desconocida" que es el id_pm y no se muy bien por qué

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir la estructura de ambas tamblas porfavor?

Comment: y si me añades el resultadodel `var_export($sql1)` tambien estaria bien

Comment: Lo acabo de añadir todo

Comment: A ver... lo unico que veo es que en el `INSERT`, en la parte de `VALUES`, mas concretamente en el segundo valor, le falta una comilla justo antes de "*test*"... lo que pasa es que no lo entiendo, porque en el codigo si esta puesta la comilla... Puedes hacer un `var_export($listaAlta)` por favor?

Comment: Es mas, me acabo de fijar y pasa lo mismo en todos los que pone "*test*", ya sea en mayusculas o en minusculas...

Comment: Pues, lo acabo de ejecutar de nuevo, comprobando las comillas y lo he puesto de nuevo en mi pregunta. Lo único que no hace, por algo que no consigo ver, es copiar los datos a la otra tabla.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137262/discussion-between-adrigo-and-monica).

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias!!!! Era el ID que se repetía en ambas tablas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monica, si las tablas son idénticas como dices (tienen los mismos campos), podrías hacer algo así en el modo más parecido a tu código actual...

```
require 'funcs/funcs.php';
require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$checkbox = $_POST['casilla1'];

foreach ($checkbox as $value) {
        
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO pms_historico ".
                " SELECT * FROM pms ".
                    " WHERE id_pm = $value";
    $resultado1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);

    $sql = "Delete From pms where id_pm = ".$value."";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

}
```

Si hubiera algún campo diferente, podrías hacer explícitos los campos de la tabla del `INSERT INTO` y hacer un `SELECT` de los mismos `FROM pms`, pero siempre mejor, para duplicar, hacerlo directo.

También **se podría mejorar la eficiencia** (haciendo sólo dos llamadas a la BBDD en lugar de *2xnúmero de ids*) teniendo los IDs en un array, y poniendo como condición (tanto para la inserción como para los borrados) `WHERE id_pm IN (".implode(',',$arr_values).")"`:

```
require 'funcs/funcs.php';
require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$checkbox = $_POST['casilla1'];

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO pms_historico ".
            " SELECT * FROM pms ".
                " WHERE id_pm  IN (".implode(',',$checkbox).") ";
$resultado1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);

$sql = "Delete From pms WHERE id_pm IN (".implode(',',$checkbox).") ";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Hago notar que tu `if($sql1){` del final no sé para qué es, porque $sql1 siempre va a tener un contenido que acabas de dar (`INSERT INTO...`)

**Referencia: [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)**

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios. Usando el código que me indicas, pasa lo mismo. Los datos se borran de la tabla principal pero no se copian a la de histórico.

Comment: Y el if($sql1) es para que me salga el mensaje de "'Registro guardado" si el código se ejecuta sin errores

Comment: el ìf($sql1)` siempre sea `true` y por tanto mostrara el mensaje de dentro porque es un `string` asique no tiene mucho sentido...

Comment: Monica, pues si no te hace el `INSERT INTO` ya no me explico por qué. Y lo de `if($sql1)`, como dice @adrigo, es una condición que siempre se cumplirá. De hecho, me imagino que te imprime el texto y en cambio dices que no te lo copia a la tabla del histórico, ¿no? Tendría sentido si compruebas `$resultado1`, pero no `$sql1`

Comment: Cierto, lo que hace el if($sql1) imprimir el texto como que se ha copiado el resutado, pero no se copia. Y como os digo, no se muy bien porqué. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y comentarios.

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias por toda tu aportación.

Comment: Está bien, pero 2 cosas... 1) Decías que no te iba en tu comentario anterior, y después que está solucionado pero no sabemos cuál era el último problema. Puedes ayudar a los demás explicando qué es lo que pasaba || 2) si te vale como correcta o lo has solucionado con esta respuesta, puedes marcarla como válida.

Comment: El problema estaba en que intentaba copiar un id que ya estaba en la otra tabla.   Borré la tabla de histórico y ejecuté de nuevo el codigo y copio sin errores los datos de una tabla a otra.